# Turning List Comprehension into Functional Application

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I have a function which was written in list comprehension. As a learning I decided to try to convert this function into a functional application using map, zip, fold, etc. I am having a really hard time converting this particular one.

It might seem unreasonable for what it is doing, but it is part of a bigger function and I want to get this piece working first.

```
combination :: Int -> [a] -> [([a],[a])]
combination 0 xs     = [([],xs)]
combination n (x:xs) = [ (x:ys,zs) | (ys,zs) <- combination (n-1) xs ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a `map`:

```
combination :: Int -> [a] -> [([a],[a])]
combination 0 xs     = [([],xs)]
combination n (x:xs) = map (\(ys, zs) -> (x:ys,zs)) (combination (n-1) xs)
```

Comment: Wow, I think I was really over complicating this by trying to get rid of the first pattern match of `combination 0 xs = [([],xs)]`. Thank you so much for the great response.